# How to put an asterisk sign beside a text field if the text field is empty?

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

How it will work? If i press the button and the text field is empty it will display a asterisk sign besides the textfiled.

```
if(txtfname.getText().equals(" ")){
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Missing field");
  jLabel20.setText("*");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
if(txtfname.getText().trim().isEmpty())//Trim removes unnecessary chars is empty checks for emptyness
//show *
```

Remember `trim()` on `null` string can generate `NullPointerException` so you should also check for `null` before.

Comment: what is NPE? I think abbreviation like that could get Newbie confused. I believed you meant NullPointerException?

Comment: @codingbiz could well be - but we all have a big friend named Google ;-)